# HTTP code 302 encountered when deploying on Google App Engine Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-endpoints

When developing for App Engine Endpoints in Java using the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients), after running endpoints.cmd with the appropriate parameters and deploying in GAE, the dev server shows the proper endpoints at `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis`, but accessing the explorer for the production version on GAE shows old endpoints at `https://<my-app>.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis`.

The error was traced to the `HTTP 302` (moved temporarily) code found in the Logs of the production app for access to `/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs`. Until that clears (i.e., gives HTTP 200), Google's servers won't be able to serve the endpoint (See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058819/20386)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error stems in part due to inconsistent documentation. While the official documentation's sample web.xml uses a `<security-constraint>` block, that of the [sample tictactoe app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java/blob/master/war/WEB-INF/web.xml) does not.

If you are getting a `HTTP 302` status code, check the following two things (from [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/endpoints-trusted-testers/2jyFxm4WEjY/discussion)):

1. in your .api file in WEB-INF, change `http` to `https` in the `bns` declaration,
2. remove the `<security-constraint>` block from your web.xml.

The above worked for me; not sure what the security constraint bit was about. Maybe a GAE admin can improve this answer?

Comment: the post has restricted access it seems :(