# Google Cloud Endpoint API returns 500 error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I applied the answer found in 
[HTTP code 302 encountered when deploying on Google App Engine Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15246039/2137244)

The 302 problem is gone, the API has become visible in the deployed application, but now I'm getting this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

The application log shows the 200 response for this request though:

```
2013-03-07 18:57:10.992 /_ah/spi/DeviceSyncEndPoint.listDevices 200 185ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
216.31.219.19 - - [07/Mar/2013:18:57:10 -0800] "POST /_ah/spi/DeviceSyncEndPoint.listDevices HTTP/1.1" 200 86 - "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11" "racermanager-hrd.appspot.com" ms=186 cpu_ms=47 cpm_usd=0.000010 instance=00c61b117ceb47410221ae438f2cbe7fc958
```

Where the 500 error is coming from and how do I  troubleshoot it?

Comment: Can you provide the code for DeviceSyncEndPoint?

Comment: Here it is: @Api(
 name = "syncapi",
 version = "v1",
 description = "Device Sync API",
 scopes = {"ss0", "ss1"},
 audiences = {"aa0", "aa1"},
 clientIds = {"cc0", "cc1"},
 defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE
    )
    public class DeviceSyncEndPoint {

    @ApiMethod(
 name = "devices.list",
 path = "devices",
 httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET,
 scopes = {"s0", "s1"},
 audiences = {"a0", "a1"},
 clientIds = {"c0", "c1"}
 )
    public List<String> listDevices() {
 LinkedList<String> devices = new LinkedList<String>();
 devices.add("12345");
 return devices;
    }
 
    }

Comment: @DanHolevoet Dan, were you able to figure out what causing SystemServiceServlet to produce 500 error? Thanks!