# Endpoint works fine on local, but gives me a 500 Internal Error on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a project where when I do a post or get to an endpoint on my local it works fine, but when I do the same exact thing on app engine I get back:

```
{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "internalError",
   "message": "Internal Error"
  }
],
 "code": 500,
"message": "Internal Error"
}
}
```

I have checked my data and it all looks the same. In the log I can see that the method completes successfully and I see no error message, stack trace, etc.

What gives? Thanks!

Comment: Not that this helps much, but it looks like  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18952299/399704 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15286191/399704 have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Though i do not know your code i assume your cloud endpoints have a return value like String[] or List, which doesn't work when deployed but does work on devserver.
Define a class for your return type and use that class, Like

```
public class StringResult {
  String result;
  /* getters and setters '/
}
```

And yes, i did answer the same thing in the other thread so technically this question is a duplicate if the answer solves the issue ;-)