# Google Cloud end point API doesn't update

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

There is a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047744/gae-cloud-endpoints-api-not-updating-after-deploy) but it's not the same.
There is no error from the Admin Logs.

```
2013-07-02 09:35:21 xxxx@gmail.com  Successfully updated API configuration  version=70.368500704938526122
2013-07-02 09:35:21 xxxx@gmail.com  Set the default version server=default, version=70.2013-07-02T13:35:01Z
2013-07-02 09:35:07 xxxx@gmail.com  Successfully updated API configuration  version=70
2013-07-02 09:35:06 xxxx@gmail.com  Completed update of a new alternate version version=70.2013-07-02T13:35:01Z
2013-07-02 09:35:02 xxxx@gmail.com  Deployed a new version  version=70.2013-07-02T13:35:01Z
```

There is no error from the application logs too

```
2013-07-02 09:35:43.029 /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 200 17ms 1kb
2013-07-02 09:35:30.948 /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages 204 17ms 0kb
I 2013-07-02 09:35:30.946 Endpoints: https://xxxx.appspot.com/_ah/api/scheduleendpoint@v1 SAVED
I 2013-07-02 09:35:30.946 Endpoints: https://xxxx.appspot.com/_ah/api/terminalendpoint@v1 SAVED
I 2013-07-02 09:35:30.946 Endpoints: https://xxxx.appspot.com/_ah/api/deviceinfoendpoint@v1 SAVED
I 2013-07-02 09:35:30.946 Endpoints: https://xxxx.appspot.com/_ah/api/messageEndpoint@v1 SAVED
2013-07-02 09:35:27.997 /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages 204 5883ms 0kb
I 2013-07-02 09:35:27.994 Endpoints: xxxx.appspot.com made default app version
2013-07-02 09:35:27.884 /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 200 5820ms 1kb
I 2013-07-02 09:35:27.884 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
```

There is a strange thing, before when the endpoints is deployed, the log shows `....@v1 OK`  but not it's `...@v1 SAVED`

So this may be possible reason and how may I be able to correct it? Thanks a lot

Comment: are you still seeing this observation or was it only during a particular time period

Comment: work now. it never shows OK but the api works now. Thanks.