# Google Endpoints API working in development but not when deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to deploy a cloud endpoints api so I can use it on my website. 
When I run it locally the api works fine (loads and works properly and doesn't give an error).
However, when I upload to the web it doesn't load. (when I check api explorer I just get the yellow loading bar near the search and I can't get it to load using JavaScript)

I checked both the logs on the local machine and the logs in the developers console but their isn't anything informative about the endpoints

Based on suggestion here [GAE cloud endpoints - Api not updating after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047744/gae-cloud-endpoints-api-not-updating-after-deploy)

I checked my logs and found the following line "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200

My endpoints has the following header

```
@endpoints.api(name='treesruleApi', version='v1')
```

In my app.yaml I have

```
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: api.APPLICATION
```

I am not really expecting a solution but I would love to know other things I can try.

P.S. Below is my whole app.yaml for reference (without the application:application line)

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /bootstrap
  static_dir: bootstrap
- url: /style
  static_dir: style
- url: /flot
  static_dir: flot
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: api.APPLICATION
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /.*
  script: app.application


builtins:
- remote_api: on 
- admin_redirect: on  

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

Comment: In your request logs for `/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs`, do you see a `200` response code, or a `4xx` / `5xx`?  Do you have a Traceback / stack trace in the logs?

Comment: 200 I thought I copied that! i will update my question

Comment: I assume your `api.py` contains something like `APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([treesruleApi])`?

Comment: Yeah It's ]the class name as opposed to the endpoints name though

Comment: Yep, my mistake. So, if you go to `https://your-project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`, do you get redirected to `apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=<your-api-url>`, but then you don't see `treesruleApi API` in the list of *Services*?

Comment: Nothing turns up in services, all versions and request history

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72174/discussion-between-treesrule14-and-tx802).