# Endpoints: /_ah/api/ returns 404 after update

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Problem fixed via Google Cloud support:

I removed the /_ah/spi/* handler from my endpoints yaml file, and the

```
- url: /.*
  script: api.app
```

did not instantiate the endpoint.

It used to work before since the API was deployed for the previous version, but with the new version, there was nothing explicit to deploy the endopoints. So handlers need to be

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: api.app
- url: /.*
  script: api.app
```

Keeping the issue below for reference purposes

---

I've just deployed a new version of my application, and calls to http://app.appspot.com/_ah/api/app/version/method now return a 404. It worked perfectly before the update.

However, there's no trace at all in the logs, and no instance launched when I call/ping those URIs.

While if I call /_ah/whatever/app/version/method, I still have a 404, but it appears in my module logs, and it has the following message

```
{"state": "APPLICATION_ERROR", "error_message": "Not Found"}
```

The app is configured using modules, my app.yaml is defined with

```
application: appname
version: 2015-04-07
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: api.api.app
- url: /.*
  script: www.www.app
  secure: always

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

And, in api/api.yaml

```
application: appname
module: default
version: 2015-04-07
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: api.app

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

I've updated the app to serve this new version in the admin console, and all other modules work perfectly.

Also, I can't see my API in the API explorer, https://appname.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer returns an empty list (while I see it when running the dev server on localhost).

- **Update**: I've just noticed, looking at @bossylobster reply in [GAE cloud endpoints - Api not updating after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047744/gae-cloud-endpoints-api-not-updating-after-deploy), that I do not have "Successfully updated API configuration" in my logs after the "Completed update of a new alternate version". However, I have "API deletion serving" at about the time everything started to be 404. Yet, I have no idea why there's this API deletion query in my logs. Any idea of what can be wrong?

That's an app in production and so the mobile version is down at the moment. I'm happy to send the app ID to a devrel in PM if that helps.

Comment: have you tried redeploying? sometime GAE hiccups and misses little details like getting the APIs back up.

Comment: @jirungaray that was an issue with handlers, which were not properly configured for the new app version. Updated the issue to detail the answer

Comment: You should actually answer your own question instead of posting the answer directly on top of the question.