# Google app engine: Application deploying but no API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I am deploying an application on Google App Engine.  In the admin logs, I see that it deploys successfully, "Completed update of a new default version".  But I never see the "API configuration update serving" message after this.

When I go to API explorer, there is nothing under services.

Note: When I added the same @endpoints.method to another Application, the API is showing when I deploy this app.  So, I am assuming it is something silly.  My code and output of the deploy is below.  I would appreciate any pointers!

**Output of deploy**

** Running appcfg.py with the following flags:
    --oauth2_credential_file=~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens update
12:06 AM Application: apns-push; version: 1
12:06 AM Host: appengine.google.com
12:06 AM 
Starting update of app: apns-push, version: 1
12:06 AM Getting current resource limits.
12:06 AM Scanning files on local disk.
12:06 AM Cloning 1 static file.
12:06 AM Cloning 3 application files.
12:06 AM Compilation starting.
12:06 AM Compilation completed.
12:06 AM Starting deployment.
12:06 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
12:06 AM Deployment successful.
12:06 AM Checking if updated app version is serving.
12:06 AM Completed update of app: apns-push, version: 1
12:06 AM Uploading index definitions.
If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 0 **

**Code**

```
@endpoints.api( name='apns_server',
            version='v1',
            allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID,API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
            scopes=[EMAIL_SCOPE])
class APNSPush(remote.Service):
"""Conference API v0.1"""

# - - - Profile objects - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -    @endpoints.method(RegisterForm, BooleanMessage,
        path='registerDevice', http_method='POST', name='registerDevice')
def registerDevice(self, request):
    """Update & return user profile."""
    ret_val=True
    prof = Profile()

    buf =  'received device Token'   
    logging.debug(buf)

    for field in ('userID', 'deviceUUID','deviceToken'):
            if hasattr(request, field):
                val = getattr(request, field)
                if val:
                    setattr(prof, field, str(val))
                    buf =  '%s %s' % (field,val)   
                    logging.debug(buf)
                else:
                    buf =  'Could not get value for field %s' % (field)   
                    logging.debug(buf)
                    ret_val=False
            else:
                buf =  '%s not present' % (field)   
                logging.debug(buf)
                ret_val=False  
    prof.put()

    return BooleanMessage(data=ret_val)

api = endpoints.api_server([APNSPush])
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047744/gae-cloud-endpoints-api-not-updating-after-deploy ...?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  I was using the GoogleAppEngineLauncher UI based app to deploy.  While adding a New AppEngine project (using the left click --> New option), I specified both the Application ID in addition to the folder with application files.  In this case, the launcher expects the files to be under a folder with name = ApplicationID.

Solution is not specify the Application-ID.  The launcher will use the application ID in the app.yaml and everything is now good to go.